# Passing Data to D3 from Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a chart using D3 and Angular, using data retrieved from a database.
The code below shows that chart_scan_times is the array that I want, but the graph is not displaying the data.  Most like a problem with the '{{ }}' syntax on my EJS page, but I have tried including <%= %>, etc around the passing of chart_scan_times to data without it working

```
    {{chart_scan_times}}
  <bars data='{{chart_scan_times}}'></bars>
```

[Displays this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nUV5.png)

The code below correctly displays the graph

```
      <bars data='40,4,14,22,99'></bars>
```

[Displays This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyCR2.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Create a true array, you are just passing in a string of numbers.

Comment: The string Is split on commas after being sent to the angular directive.  it works hard coding in an array as well

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `data` attribute takes a string and you are passing an array. Try `chart_scan_times = dataArr.join()` from your controller or wherever you initialize this expression